# Calculate ~100 by hand

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

If I print out `~100` in Java, I get `-101`. I'm trying to work this out by hand.

The NOT (`~`) operator inverts all bits.

`100` in binary is `00000000000000000000000001100100`.

inverting its bits gives:

`11111111111111111111111110011011`

Now what? How do I get `-101`?

Comment: What exactly where you expecting a binary operation on a signed number to do?

Comment: Do you understand why `~0` is `-1`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Java uses two's complement (see [§4.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2) Primitive Types and Values)  To negate, you take the complement and add one.

```
-x = ~x + 1
~x = -x - 1
~100 = -100 - 1
```

Another way to think about it is to note:

```
11111111111111111111111111111111 = -1
```

then do:

```
  11111111111111111111111111111111 (-1)
- 11111111111111111111111110011011 (~x)
=                          1100100 (100)

-1 - ~x = 100
-1 - 100 = ~x
~x = -101
```

Answer (score 0):

Most systems today work with the 2's complement system. In this system positive numbers are same as in the old binary system, while negative numbers are different (this help map another negative number using the same amount of bits)

If you want to take a number in this system and translate it back to old fashion binary:

~(NegNumber)+1